# Python Regex matching choice between "\*" (literal Asterisk char) OR "\s" (Space)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the "D" lines and **capture the characters** 2,3,4 and 5 in a similar dataset to:

```
S    7....                        <- line 1
         associated random data   <- line 2
D*EX 0....                        <- line 3
         associated random data   <- line 4
C    0....                        <- line 5
         associated random data   <- line 6
D E  6....                        <- line 7
         associated random data   <- line 8
         associated random data   <- line 9
D    3....                        <- line 10
         associated random data   <- line 11
D O  3....                        <- line 12
         associated random data   <- line 13
         associated random data   <- line 14
```

i.e. I don't want to *just* capture ^D.* The "EX" chars can change and I'll need to differentiate between them later.

The problem I'm having seems to be the choice between an "*" and a " " (space) in the second character (column).

However specifying a choice between "*" and "\s" does not seem to match on the line "D*EX 0...."

```
re.compile(r'''^(^[D]               # Match "D"
                [\*|\s]         <-- # Match either "*" or " "
                [A-Z{1,2}\s|\s{3}]  # match either "EX" + "" OR match 3x" "
.*?)^[A-Z]''', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE |re.VERBOSE)  # match anything else if there...
```

Matches and outputs => `D EX 6....` and `D    3....`

If I implicitly specify the "*", I do indeed end up with a line match, but of course the additional lines are not matched.

```
re.compile(r'''^(^[D]               # Match "D"
                [\*]            <-- # Match ONLY "*"
                [A-Z{1,2}\s|\s{3}]  # match either "EX" + "" OR match 3x" "
.*?)^[A-Z]''', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE |re.VERBOSE)  # match anything else if there...
```

Matches and outputs only => `D*EX 0....`

It was suggested to me that I try using a non-capturing group and whilst NC groups are new but making a bit of sense to me, I may still want that captured output and a NC group with the original choice between "*" and "\s", still does not match. I have played with a number of combinations but that output is consistent with the below.

```
re.compile(r'''^(^[D]               # Match "D"
                (?:[\*|\s]      <-- # non-capturing group match either "*" or " "
                [A-Z{1,2}\s|\s{3}]  # match either "EX" + "" OR match 3x" "
.*?)^[A-Z]''', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE |re.VERBOSE)  # match anything else if there...
```

Matches and outputs => `D EX 0....` and `D    0....`

Any suggestions/recommendations are appreciated; I'm going around in circles here :O

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting expressions within `[]`, e.g. `[A-Z{1,2}\s|\s{3}]`?

Comment: Could you paste in the flags you're using so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: @AaronHall updated data set - i'm trying to match the data chunks between the sets of ^[A-Z]

Comment: @devnull just a boolean match  between the first set "A-Z{1,2}\s" and the second set "\s{3}"

Comment: @Ovid `[]` denotes a character class; if you want to match a literal `[` or `]` then you'd need to escape it.

Comment: @Ovid you never really made clear what you were aiming to get. Did you want the associated data? Or just the 2-5 columns, not even including the digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setup:

```
import re

txt = '''S    7....                        <- line 1
         associated random data   <- line 2
D*EX 0....                        <- line 3
         associated random data   <- line 4
C    0....                        <- line 5
         associated random data   <- line 6
D E  6....                        <- line 7
         associated random data   <- line 8
         associated random data   <- line 9
D    3....                        <- line 10
         associated random data   <- line 11
D O  3....                        <- line 12
         associated random data   <- line 13
         associated random data   <- line 14'''

flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE |re.VERBOSE
```

And here's some sample usage:

```
re1 = re.compile('''^(D.*?)\d''', flags)    
print re.findall(re1, txt)
```

which returns:

```
['D*EX ', 'D E  ', 'D    ', 'D O  ']
```

I realized you're probably wanting all of the associated random data, and all of this stuff in the middle is pretty irrelevant if you want it all, all that matters are the end pieces:

Eliminate the multiline flag

```
flags = re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE
```

Now start at the beginning of each new line, look for the D immediately following, and capture it and everything after nongreedily to a bookend of a newline with another character or the end of the string.

```
re1 = re.compile(
  r'''(?:^|\n) # noncapturing, assert start of string or newline
      (D.*?)   # capture D and everything after it
      (?=\n[A-Z]|$) #lookahead, newline cap char or end of string?
  ''', flags)


for i in  re.findall(re1, txt):
    print i
```

Which prints:

```
D*EX 0....                        <- line 3
         associated random data   <- line 4
D E  6....                        <- line 7
         associated random data   <- line 8
         associated random data   <- line 9
D    3....                        <- line 10
         associated random data   <- line 11
D O  3....                        <- line 12
         associated random data   <- line 13
         associated random data   <- line 14
```

And that's what you're looking for.

**Postscript**

As a postscript, I got this far down the rabbit hole using multiline before giving up on that. Maybe you can see sort of what you were doing wrong.

```
^((D[\*\s]([A-Z]\s{2}|[A-Z]{2}\s|\s{3}).*)$(?!^\n[A-Z]))
```

For one thing, don't use pipes inside of square brackets unless you want them as a literal possibility.

Comment: @AaronHall Wow - that's awesome. I certainly do see where I went wrong and I appreciate you taking the time to explain it. Upvote for you, up vote for you. Upvotes for everyone!

Comment: @devnull yeah it makes sense now; everyone's gotta start somewhere - thanks for chipping in!